# How to launch supertest files in node?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest

I have a node/typescript server. I wish to test the api routes with supertest. I've written my first test, but cannot start it because

> TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/myname/Desktop/Code/Reapr/server/src/tests/search.test.ts

The test.ts file is:

```js
import request from "supertest";
import { server } from "../index";

describe("GET /user/:id", () => {
  it("return user information", (done) => {
    request(server)
      .get("/user/123")
      .set("Accept", "application/json")
      .expect("Content-Type", /json/)
      .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

The package.json is:

```js
{
  "name": "my-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts",
    "start": "npm run build && node build/index.js",
    "test": "node src/tests/search.test.ts"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.25.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.2.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.5.0",
    "nodemailer-express-handlebars": "^4.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.0.1",
    "stripe": "^8.142.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.10.4",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.13",
    "@types/stripe": "^8.0.417",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  }
}
```

Also, this error is only here when I explicitly write the script `"test": node src/tests/search.test.ts"`. If I write `"test": "jest"`, I got this error:

> jest: command not found

So, how to properly launch my supertests files, if possible all at once, instead of changing the script line for every file?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a `ts` file directly with `ts-node`.

```
"test": "ts-node src/tests/search.test.ts"
```

Or build it to `js` file and run it with `node`.

To execute `jest` command, you have to install it, and you are using Typescript (?) then you also need `ts-jest`:

```
npm install ts-jest jest -D
```

Create a configuration file for jest: `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  testMatch: [
    '**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)',
    '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)',
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
};
```

Now, try to execute jest: `npx jest`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! So, I can now launch the files, but the server crashes with this new error: ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. Basically, the routes hits a middleware to authenticate the user (I've added .set("Cookie", ["_id=567;locale=en"])), and then the route is triggered.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 It not related to this question, then you can try to research by yourself or create a new SO question.

Answer (score 0):

in package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/test/setup.ts"
    ]
  },
```

jest does not understand what typescript is, "ts-jest" will add typescript support.

"setupFilesAfterEnv" is optional. if you have a setup file, it will run this to set up extra configuration like adding "beforeAll, beforeEach" etc.

here is the dependencies you need to install for testing environment:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "jest": "^26.6.1",
    "supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.3"
  }
```

- also add this script to package.json:

  ```
  "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache"
  ```

--no-cache flag is related to typescript setup. jest sometimes does not catch the changes in typescript files.

lastly you imported server but make sure you set up server.ts properly. here I explained: [supertest not found error testing express endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122778/supertest-not-found-error-testing-express-endpoint/57368925#57368925)

this should set your testing environment

Comment: The server keeps crashing with an error 500. `You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.`

Comment: are u sure you set "preset" correctly. maybe u made a typo

Comment: it does not recognize the environment. can you upgrade your node.